# How to name a folder with today's date and time?

Tags: windows, backup, time, copy, date

So i have this lil .bat setup

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %date%
Copy D:\000Back\list.txt D:\111Back\
CD D:\111Back\
copy list.txt %date%_%time%.txt
ECHO done
PAUSE
```

The second copy command never goes through, that might be because are there dots(.) in the date and time?
So, it cannot rename it?

I'm trying to make a .bat file that will make backups for me, so having them named the day they are made would be great.

Thanks if you can help, there's probably a really easy solution, but im really only just dipping my toes into doing stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution, use Powershell instead of the antiquated command prompt:

```powershell
Copy-Item D:\000Back\list.txt ("D:\111Back\" + (get-date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm") + ".txt")
```

It's a oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

Using *.bat file you can do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
Copy D:\000Back\list.txt D:\111Back\
CD D:\111Back\
set mydate=%date:/=%
set mytime=%time::=-%
set mytimestamp=%mydate: =_%_%mytime:.=_%
copy list.txt "%mytimestamp%.txt"
ECHO done
PAUSE
```